# infrastructure - 2 servers , 3 applications

Tags: sql, web, infrastructure

if you only have 2 servers, but you need to install sql server, a web application, and an reporting application, which 2 would you put on the same server and which one would you leave standalone.
Initially i would say the sql server should be solo.  But the reporting application suggest it be on a solo server as well and if you have to install the reporting application on the server with the web application there are some port/ip configurations that have to be done to make them work together.

what would most experts suggest?

Comment: Are the two servers identical?  What is being hosted.  I doubt there is any useful answer that can be made without specifics.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any other information, SQL Server on its own physical box if possible.

Comment: Hello, Well this is a very small shop. they have 2 servers . server 1 is less powerful than server 2. server 1 has sql server and cold fusion. this was the first server they had. then they go server 2 for tableau and spec'd out the server for tableau. my recommendation to them was to virtualize server 2 and put cold fusion and tableau on server 2 and leave sql server on server 1.  the problem is i don't know if they can do all that reconfiguration or not.  if they can reconfigure, or buy new hardware i have best practices that i know to implement. however....

Comment: if they say they have to keep things they way they are and just choose which applications to put together on the same box, i would too say put sql server on a box alone.. the only big issue is cold fusion and tableau are both web applications.. so i don' t know if they would have to change IP or Ports to make them work together and then have to tell customers a new url to get to either of them...

Answer (score 0):

Put SQL on one, the web-application on the other.  If the reporting application is very high throughput, then you could consider putting it on the same box as the sql server.  If the reporting application is very low load, or does most of its work during off hours, then it doesn't really matter where it goes.  But all things being equal, you should try to keep it off of the database server.  Another option is to virtualize your second server and put each app on it's own vm, leaving the second physical server dedicated to the database.